# How do I evaluate $\int \frac{\arccos \frac{x}{2}}{4+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus

> $$\displaystyle \int \frac{\arccos \frac{x}{2}}{4+x^2}\text{d}x$$

My attempt:

$x=2\cos \theta\;\; dx=-2\sin \theta d\theta$

$\displaystyle -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\theta \sin \theta}{1+\cos^2\theta}d\theta$

Integration by parts $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\theta\arctan(\cos\theta)-\frac{1}{2}\int \arctan(\cos \theta)d\theta$ How do I solve it from here?

Comment: i think this integral can not expressed by the known elementary functions

Comment: should'n it be $arctan(cos(\theta))$?

Comment: What is *the value* of an indefinite integral?

Comment: According to WolframAlpha : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+arccos(x%2F2)%2F(x%5E2%2B4)

Comment: How did $\arccos$ become $\arctan$?

Comment: I do not have answer of that question.